# Steps to install Ubuntu 13.04 alongside Windows 8

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-13.04, ubuntu-13.10

I am currently using Windows 8 Pro in my system. It is an assembled system. I tried a lot of times to install Ubuntu 13.04, but I failed. In the installation I was able to reach up to the page on which I choose "Install Ubuntu alongside windows". Then I pressed Install button. The error occurred now. A black screen appeared, somethings were written on it like "Speech dispatch disabled","Stopped by signal 15" and some other texts too. Also my disc get ejected at the same time. Is there a solution for this ? Or can I install Ubuntu using any other ways ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have Windows 8 pro running alongwith Ubuntu 13.04 dualboot running pefectly. Although i didn't install it using a disc. I made a bootable USB drive using PowerISO and then installed from it. To install using bootable USB u can refer this [link to create a bootable disk](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)

Comment: What if the above mentioned error occurred again ?

Comment: download a Desktop Image of ubuntu 13.04 (Raring Ringtail) for PC (Intel x86) as given in this link http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/" and try again. That's the one i'm currently running.